# Woocommerce REST API (Fetch products posted by a certain user)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering if there's any way to fetch Woocommerce products posted by a certain user "XYZ"? I have gone through the official documentation but didn't find any direct API call for that.
I'm thinking an alternate way to achieve this by assigning a tag to those products or something similar to it and then fetch them using the respective API call but I was just wondering if there's any direct way to do so.

Thank you!